# shell script variable with special characters

Tags: shell, unix

Currently I have multiple `config.sh` files. I want to append these contents to another files. So I am using `cat config_file >> file_to_apend`.

Now I want to have single config file, so that I can `source` it and use variables, each variable will have config file contents. Now eahc of config file has multiple variables to export.

e.g.

config file_contents:

```
var1="hello"
var2={ ... }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by special characters, `cat` uses utf-8 by default. Maybe use `iconv` instead of `cat` ? This may help, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/characters-encodings-supported-by-more-cat-and-less . Otherwise we need to see the output.

Comment: If you are just trying to get rid of the shebang at the top, awk will work for this. To skip the first two lines, `awk 'NR>2{print $0;}' config_1.sh >> config_global.sh`

Comment: @JessicaPennell I think you misunderstood the question, i have modified it now.

Comment: I do not understand - `Now I want to have single config` great so do it. You did not state any problems in your post. In the spirit of this forum, please ask a question, see [ask].

Comment: debonair, we still need more information. What do the variables have in common? If you are just trying to pull out all the variable assignments that can be done with a huge "but" with `grep -P '^[^=]+=[^=]+$' config_1.sh >> config.sh` and then possibly `sort -u -i config.sh` to get rid of duplicates and then manually move your shebang back to the top. But that's a bad idea, since you aren't handling any logic that sets variables, variable name collisions, and a wealth of other things. That is why I picked the far safer option with awk earlier. We really need a full example.

Comment: `var2={ ... }` -- what does this signify? Is this meant to be JSON data? Note that bash is quite limited in terms of available data structures: bash has numerically indexed arrays and associative arrays, but the array values must be strings: no nested arrays are possible. If you really need to code in bash, your config must be simple. Or, use a tool like `jq` to parse JSON data and extract values for (possibly nested) object keys.

Answer (score 0):

The goal you have in mind cannot be safely accomplished. It can be accomplished and I will demonstrate how. The command to make this happen in full, and the best possible answer to your question, is

```
for file in config*
do
  [ "${file}" == "config.sh" ] && continue
  grep -P '^[^=]+=[^=]+$' $file >> config.sh
done
```

(in other words, "for every config file, append all lines with a single equals sign)"

These are the reasons this is not a good idea, and why you should instead edit config.sh by hand.

**Case 1 : The case of the colliding names**

In this scenario, config_1.sh has

```
var1="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

config_2.sh has

```
var1="sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow"
```

config.sh, after running the above command, now has

```
var1="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
var1="sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow"
```

When this executes, you end up with var1 from config_2.sh **only**.

**Case 2 : The derived variable**

In this scenario, config_1.sh has

```
var1="the $adjective brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

When you source config.sh you end up with

```
var1="the  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

**Case 3: The variable set a different way**

In this scenario, config_1.sh has

```
. another_script.sh
```

another_script.sh sets several environment variables. None of these make it into config.sh

**Case 4: The maintenance headache**

In this scenario, both config_1.sh and config_2.sh have

```
var1="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

config.sh now has two copies of this. You may filter out down to unique lines with the sort command. However, if you have two variables that depend on each other, e.g.

```
var3="quick"
var2="the $var3 brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

This will work before the sort command and stop working after the sort command. On the other hand, not sorting can leave you with as many copies of the same line as you have configuration files.

**Case 5 : The broken regex**

There are several other problems you may be able to come up with. Text containing an equals sign, using backslash to continue lines, etc. Problems of that nature, surrounding our definition of assignment, I did not go into since they are too numerous to mention. Suffice to say, it is impossible to come up with a regular expression that matches every possible variable assignment; we run into the halting problem.

**Awk : A safer way**

Let's say to get around all these problems, you made sure

- Every variable assignment does not contain other variables
- All the variables in the script are in the same place
- No two config files have variables that have the same names

Let's go even further. Let's say all your config files are nothing *but* variable assignments.

In this example, your first two lines are still in the way

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To just get rid of those first two lines we change the script earlier :

```
for file in config*
do
  [ "${file}" == "config.sh" ] && continue
  awk 'NR>2{print $0;}' $file >> config.sh
done
```

(in other words, "after line 2, collect everything else into config.sh")